# string pointers in C indexing

Tags: c, string, pointers

If I have:

```
char *tokenPtr = "testingpointerindex"
```

and I want to access everything after the 4th character, how would I go about that? I tried :

```
char *tokenPtr = "testingpointerindex";

char *host = tokenPtr + 4;
printf("%s\n",host);

return host;
```

It's just an outake but I hope it gives enough info, I get a bus error.
Thanks

EDIT:

The full code

```
char * getHost(char *buf){
char *tokenPtr;
tokenPtr = strtok(buf, "\r\n" ); 
printf("got token\n");
while ( tokenPtr != NULL ) { 
    if(strncmp(tokenPtr,"Host",4) == 0){
        break;
    }
    else{
        tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, "\r\n" );
    }
}
char *host = tokenPtr + 7;
printf("%s\n",host);
    return host;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *msg = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n Host: www.google.com\r\n\r\n";
getHost(msg);


}
```

Comment: You want to get the sub-string after the 4th character, so you did `tokenPtr + 7`?  Where did you pull that `7` out of?

Comment: ohh sorry, my mistake, I just want everything after an nth index, I realise my code and my example at the start don't match, I'll edit it

Comment: The code you posted works fine.  The bus error must be somewhere else.

Comment: @drunkmonkey: are you doing something like `p = malloc(N); p += 4; free(p);`?

Comment: I've added the complete code, it's a function taken from a larger problem so the main method was jus thrown together, no return. and the http request is a simplified made up request.

Comment: @drunkmonkey I've updated my answer to reflect your new code

Comment: strtok tries to mofify the string doh!

Comment: @drunkmonkey Yeah, that's a major but subtle error ... you should still though, in production code, guard for the other issues that I've described in my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above code works fine.

However, there's one thing to mention: string literals (e.g. `"testingpointerindex"`) are non-modifiable in C.  Therefore you should use `const char *`, not `char *`.

Comment: they are not `const`, they are non-modifiable, it's a big difference.

Comment: @ouah: Could you please describe the difference?

Comment: What's the difference between `const` and non-modifiable?  Is it that you can cast `const`-ness away?

Comment: @ouah: I wouldn't say it's a "big" difference, but you make a good point.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Jason if a string literal was an array of `const`, then `char *p =  "hello";` would be not valid.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was this section of the code that was causing the problem. It is only when I added the tokenPtr + 4 line that it crashes. In the full code I'm not using a string literal but a char pointer to memory I've malloced. Does this make a difference?

Comment: @ouah I see what you're saying, but making it `const` does provide some safety from modifications even if it's not the explicit type of the object

Comment: @drunkmonkey Your problem is most likely that memory returned from `malloc` is not zeroed-out, and therefore you are over-running your buffer for the string when you attempt to print it, since `printf` with a `%s` format is looking for a NULL-terminated string.  You should allocate memory for strings using something like `strdup()`, which will automatically add a NULL-terminator.  Just remember to `free` the memory later, otherwise you will end up with a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
char *tokenPtr = "testingpointerindex";
```

to

```
static char tokenPtr[] = "testingpointerindex";
```

In your example, `tokenPtr` is a string literal and string literal are non-modifiable.

The `static` specifier is required in the second example if you plan to return a pointer to an element of the array as automatic variables are discarded at the end of a function.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I've updated this answer to conform to the new code posted by the OP's update*

In the following code, there are a couple problems:

```
while ( tokenPtr != NULL ) { 
    if(strncmp(tokenPtr,"Host",4) == 0){
        break;
    }
    else{
        tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, "\r\n" );
    }
}
char *host = tokenPtr + 7;
```

The first problem is that there is a possibility that you *could* exit the while-loop because `tokenPtr` is `NULL` ... you don't guard for that possibility.  Secondly, you assume that `tokenPtr` is pointing to a string of at least length `8` after it's been returned from `strtok`, but that's not necessarily true either (It *should* be true in your example code, but in working code it *might not* be true).

Finally, `strtok` modifies the string it processes, and you're passing it a pointer to a string-literal, which is stored in a read-only memory segment, and should not be modified.  You should call `strdup` to create your string, knowing that you'll have to call `free` on the returned pointer at some point.  So for instance:

```
int main()
{
    char *msg = strdup("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n Host: www.google.com\r\n\r\n");
    getHost(msg);

    free(msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like we had a drive-by downvoter; all answers were affected.

Comment: Yours wasn't ... I don't see what's so different from my answer and yours ... Not having vote-envy, but I'm just curious what was wrong in my answer so I can learn for next-time.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
char * getHost(char *buf){
char *tokenPtr;
tokenPtr = strtok(buf, "\r\n" ); 
printf("got token\n");

while ( tokenPtr != NULL ) { 

    if(strncmp(tokenPtr,"Host",4) == 0) break;

    else {tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, "\r\n"); break;}
}

char *host;
host = &tokenPtr[7];
printf("%s\n", host);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char msg[100] = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n Host: www.google.com\r\n\r\n";
getHost(msg);
}
```

Find out what was wrong ;)